# How to prevent UI from freezing in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

i'm getting some data from server while using URLSession in code below.
when i use this static method in code to get data in some other view controller (in view did load method i mean)to fill a collection view , my UI freeze for maybe 2 second which i think it shouldn't be like that.
where is my mistake?

```
 class RelatedData{
    static func get(_ Url:String?,completion:@escaping (Array<Game>,Int)-> Void){
    guard let url = Url else{
        return
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:url  )!)
    var gameArray = [Game]()
    var status:Int!
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {              // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        }
        do{
            print("Here we are in related games")
            let allData = try  JSONDecoder().decode(RelaedGameObject.self, from: data)
            status = allData.status
            gameArray = allData.data
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                let container = gameArray
                completion(container,status)
                gameArray.removeAll()
            }
        }
        catch{
            print(" Related Api Don't Work!!!")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

}


//And This Is View Controller Call :  


RelatedData.get(url){(Games,status) in
   if status == 1{      
    self.relatedGames = Games
    if Games.count == 0 {
     self.label.font = UIFont(name: "IRANSans", size: 13)
     self.relatedCollectionView.backgroundView = self.label
     self.relatedLabel.isHidden = false  
    }else{
      self.relatedLabel.isHidden = false
      self.relatedCollectionView.isHidden = false
      self.relatedCollectionView.reloadData()
      self.relatedCollectionView.transform =CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
     self.relatedActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
}else{
print("Err in related games")
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using Alamofire? as it will handle the multithreading for you and make it easier to manage sending and receiving data.

Comment: Please precise where the "View Controller Call" code takes place... Your problem is proable that your loading code is call within the main UI thread... Always consider using multithreading when loading something from internet in an app.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the call to `DispatchQueue.main.async` in `do-catch` statement of `get(_:completion:)` method, move it to the `controller` where you're getting the response in `completion` handler, i.e.

```
RelatedData.get(url){(Games,status) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //add your code here...
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not related the main problem and doesn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

Completion needs to be in main thread after that you can do update UI.

Add `DispatchQueue.main.async` for bad or sad path ( **catch** blocks or **return** cases )

Note: If print huge response it's freezing xcode and app too.